# A density problem

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ be the usual scalar product in ${\bf R}^n$ ($n\geq 2$) and let $B$ be the closed unit ball of ${\bf R}^n$.
Denote by $C^0(B,B)$ the space of all continuous functions from $B$ into $B$ endowed with the usual sup-metric. Denote by $\Lambda$
the set of all $f\in C^0(B,B)$ for which there exists some continuous function $\alpha_f:B\to {\bf R}$ such that the set
$$\{(x,y)\in B\times {\bf R}^n : \langle f(x)-x,y\rangle=\alpha_f(x)\}$$
is disconnected. Is it true that $\Lambda$ is dense in $C^0(B,B)$ ?

Comment: This question is aimed to provide a completely new proof of Brouwer's fixed point theorem. So, a possible positive answer should be independent of any result based on Brouwer's theorem. To prove the required density, it would be reasonable to use the Baire category theorem.